# SQLite PRIMARY key AutoIncrement doesn't work

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, auto-increment

I'm trying to a have a table with an auto incremented primary key. The SQL query for table creation is included.
Problem is the auto-increment does not work. Meaning when I insert a row with NULL as the value of `conversation_id` it just inserts `null`. I have this problem on multiple tables.

```
-- Table: conversations
CREATE TABLE conversations (
    conversation_id INTEGER (64) PRIMARY KEY
                                 UNIQUE,
    target_id       BIGINT (64),
    sender_id       BIGINT (64),
    status          STRING (16)  NOT NULL
                                 DEFAULT unseen,
    is_group        INTEGER (1)  NOT NULL
                                 DEFAULT (0),
    last_update     INTEGER (32) DEFAULT (0),
    target_name     STRING (64),
    target_photo    STRING (256),
    unread_count    INTEGER (10) DEFAULT (0),
    last_message    STRING (256) 
);
```

The following is the method I use to insert into table:

```
public Conversation addConversation(Conversation conversation) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues row = new ContentValues();

        row.put("target_id", conversation.getTargetID());
        row.put("sender_id", conversation.getSenderID());
        row.put("target_name", conversation.getTargetName());
        row.put("target_photo", conversation.getTargetPhoto());
        row.put("status", conversation.getStatus());
        row.put("unread_count", conversation.getUnreadCount());
        row.put("last_message", conversation.getLastMessage());

        conversation.setConversationID(db.insert(TBL_CONVERSATIONS, null, row));
        Log.d(TAG, "conversation added: "+conversation.getConversationID());

        db.close();

        return conversation;
    }
```

The curious thing here is when I retrieve the insert id from `insert` method it returns the correct value, but the actual database field is null.

If I understand correctly `A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement.` [[Cite]](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)

Comment: start it with underscore eg: _id.

Comment: @Krupal no success my friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From documentation:

> A table created using CREATE TABLE AS has no PRIMARY KEY and no
>   constraints of any kind. The default value of each column is NULL.

You don't have to add `UNIQUE` constraint on a COLUMN that has `PRIMARY KEY` constraint.

Explanation:

> A UNIQUE constraint is similar to a PRIMARY KEY constraint, except
>   that a single table may have any number of UNIQUE constraints.

Instead add `NOT NULL`.
This is why:

> According to the SQL standard, PRIMARY KEY should always imply NOT
>   NULL. Unfortunately, due to a bug in some early versions, this is not
>   the case in SQLite. Unless the column is an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY or the
>   table is a WITHOUT ROWID table or the column is declared NOT NULL,
>   SQLite allows NULL values in a PRIMARY KEY column. SQLite could be
>   fixed to conform to the standard, but doing so might break legacy
>   applications. Hence, it has been decided to merely document the fact
>   that SQLite allowing NULLs in most PRIMARY KEY columns.

I recommend using this Column definition:

```
CREATE TABLE conversations (
    conversation_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
...
}
```

Comment: I've tested putting `NOT NULL` and it failed inserting a row completely due to this constraint.

Comment: Finally! It seems that `AUTOINCEREMENT` should be explicitly declared.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the return value you are seeing is the row's [`ROWID`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid). A `ROWID` is a hidden column available in every table, unless explicitly removed. According to the official documentation, when you define an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, it should automatically become an alias for the `ROWID`. That's also why `AUTOINCREMENT` is not needed when you define your column in this way.

> With one exception noted below, if a rowid table has a primary key
>   that consists of a single column and the declared type of that column
>   is "INTEGER" in any mixture of upper and lower case, then the column
>   becomes an alias for the rowid. Such a column is usually referred to
>   as an "integer primary key". A PRIMARY KEY column only becomes an
>   integer primary key if the declared type name is exactly "INTEGER".
>   Other integer type names like "INT" or "BIGINT" or "SHORT INTEGER" or
>   "UNSIGNED INTEGER" causes the primary key column to behave as an
>   ordinary table column with integer affinity and a unique index, not as
>   an alias for the rowid.

See: [CREATE TABLE documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)

Either your column is not an `INTEGER`, or it is not a `PRIMARY KEY`. Taking a closer look at your create-statement I can see one or two possible culprits.

**UNIQUE vs. PRIMARY KEY**

A primary key is unique by default. According to the syntax definition (which you can find on the same documentation page as the citation above) you should choose either `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE`, not both.

**COLUMN length restrictions**

`ROWID` is already 64-bit by default. You have specified length 64, but lengths are not specified in bits. You may have specified a 64-byte integer here, which I'm sure was not intended. This should actually not be a problem however, since [SQLite ignores length-constraints](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affname). So it is not meaningful to specify them.

**TLDR**

Replace this code:

```
conversation_id INTEGER (64) PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE
```

With this:

```
conversation_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

Answer (score 2):

I just put autoincrement in the query and it works fine .

like this

```
id  integer primary key autoincrement
```